# Random Forest math pure Investigation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-forest, cart, algorithms

i am here to ask u for some material. To put you in context: I am a math pure student and i want to make an article in Random Forest (or a thesis adding other supervised learning algorithms if it is possible, idk) but i am doing it alone. So, i am asking for articles and books on the subject, but more theorical than practice because i have a lot of these books (i think it is because the job demand in data science). Something like Leo breiman articles or "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman. Thanks a lot for help, sincerely a frustrated student.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your background?

Comment: @Ben Hi, what do you want to know? i'm a math pure undergraduate student, i started my article one month ago and i don't know a lot of because Algorithms and statistic were not in my student program. I discovered the world of data science recently and I thought doing a little research on this would help me understand it better.

Comment: OK, thanks for elaborating on your being a math undergrad. Can I expect that you've recently taken an introduction to real analysis course? Does your coursework extend beyond that?

Comment: yes, I already passed the real analysis course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your level, a good starting point might be the overview article Bian and Scornet (2016) [A random forest guided tour](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11749-016-0481-7). "The present article reviews the most recent theoretical and methodological developments for random forests." You might also find a recent theoretical contribution, such as Athey, Tibshirani, and Wager (2019) [Generalized random forests](https://doi.org/10.1214/18-AOS1709), and look at references therein. A good search strategy in general is to find a seminal theoretical paper (other than Breiman, 2001, as it's cited too widely; some of the ones cited in Athey et al. or Bian and Scornet will do) and look for articles citing it on Google Scholar.

Comment: Thanks you so much, i got a lot of information there and the references take me to other articles that i think would help me